# md-datepicker in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am getting result of date in controller but I am not getting it in view

### controller.js

```
vm.profileForm = {
            name: res.result[0].name,
            mobile: res.result[0].mobile,
            email: res.result[0].email,
            DOB: $filter('date')(res.result[0].DOB, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
            Country: res.result[0].Country,
            State: res.result[0].State,
            City: res.result[0].City,
            postalCode: res.result[0].PostCode,
};
console.log(vm.profileForm.DOB);//display like '06/14/2016'
```

But i can't get this in the view

### view.html

```
<div flex style="max-width:700px;">
   <label>DOB:</label>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.profileForm.DOB" md-placeholder="Enter date">
       </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide the format of res.result[0].DOB? It is working in Codepen for me when I provide new Date() as value to DOB.

Comment: 2016-06-14T18:30:00.000Z

Comment: @Ajay I am awaiting for your response.

Comment: ng-model needs a date type variable, currently it is returning as string type variable in my system also. One Solution I found to solve your problem is instead of $filter use new Date(stringDate)...It will return the correct result... Whenever I found its solution, I will post it as an answer ...Thanks